# QnA Maker Manage knowledge - Problem Adding new URL

Tags: url, azure-cognitive-services, azure-qna-maker

I have problems adding a new URL when I manage knowledge base in QnAMaker.

I've tried adding this [Url](https://www.metlife.com.ar/soporte-servicios/preguntas-frecuentes-individual/) but I get the error:

> Failed to extract QnAs from the source "URL" - Unsupported / Invalid url(s). Failed to extract Q&A from the source.

[image: Error image]

I've tested deleting the footer, publishing the page and in this case the URL works properly.
Also, I tested other very similar URLs, like [this one](https://www.metlife.com.ar/soporte-servicios/preguntas-frecuentes-individual/corporativos/) and this has been parsed successfully.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After left feedback in azure site, QnA Maker Team fixed it. Now, the url is parsed properly.

Comment: well this is not really helpful is it.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that something with the way the questions are encoded on that page is preventing QnAMaker's services from reading the text of the question/answer pairs. In order to get those questions, I was able to copy paste the whole list:

[image: copyPasteQuestions]

I put them all into a word doc (or equivalent program), and then saved it as a PDF:

[image: pdfFAQ]

Then uploaded this to QnA Maker, where it was able to read the question/answer pairs just fine.

[image: QnASuccess]

The reason I used a PDF as opposed to a .txt file is so the alternate characters (the Spanish  ? for example) would render as well as the bullets from the final question that caused so much grief for the initial renderer.